# C++ , passing optimal argument and return type for large data

Tags: c++

I have a number of sender and receiver functions that pass data to each other hierarchically:

```
class singleton
{
 TYPE3 var; //data populated from a hierarchy
 void Receive(TYPE3 a){ var = a;}
}

class C
{
  void Receiver_from_B(TYPE2 a);
  TYPE3 intermediate_value;
  make_TYPE3(&intermediate_value){....;}//pseudo
  TYPE3 Sender(){ return intermediate_value; }  //finally sends it to a noncopyable class object
};

class B
{
  void Receiver_from_A(TYPE1 a);
  TYPE2 intermediate_value;
  make_TYPE2(&intermediate_value){....;}//pseudo
  TYPE2 Sender_to_A(){ return intermediate_value; } 
};

class A
{
  TYPE_I a;
  TYPE_II b;
  void Receiver_from_down_the-tree(TYPE_I a_){ a = a_};
  void Receiver_from_down_the-tree_(TYPE_II b_){ b = b_};
  TYPE1 intermediate_value;
  void make_TYPE1(&intermediate_value, a , b) {.....;}//pseudo
  TYPE1 Sender_to_B(){ return intermediate_value;} 
};
```

the amount of data accumulated from such a tree is relatively large and I would like to skip copying data from sender to receiver.

I guess I need a combination of `const` and `reference` for the types of arguments and return values.
I appreciate if you kindly suggest me the best type for arguments and return values.

Hope i explained the problem well.
thanks

Comment: It is hard to understand... What is the relation between those types `TYPEx`? What are the role of those classes `A`, `B` and `C`? What do you mean by `Receiver()` and `Sender()`, if those classes have no member variables to hold intermediate results?

Comment: @Ivella Sorry I think I had to be explicit.you r right,there ARE intermediate variables.Relation betwn TYPEx:simply imagine TYPE_I is struct{int a; char b;}, TYPE_II is 'int' and TYPE_III is 'char' . Then, imagine a class that receives 'int' and 'char' values through a couple of receive functions, then makes a TYPE_I variable (intermediate) and finally send(TYPE_I a) to a higher level class. And the higher class receives it through its Receive() function.. and the process continues.Note that,send and receives are NOT related to socket progg.They'r call back functions(codesynthesis xml parser).

Comment: changed the code to be more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard way to pass an object to a method/function to avoid heavy copying is using a reference to a const:

```
void my_method(const BigObject & big)
{
  // do something with big
}
```

The `&` makes it a reference and avoids deep-copy of object. The `const` grantees no the further modifications.

You have many other ways in C++ to avoid copying, such as move-constructor patterns, passing pointers (I suggest wrap them in std::shared_ptr)... . It depends on your design.

Comment: @M M. thanks a lot. I think that is what i was looking for. Just one important point. passing "const BigObject & big" to A::my_method() is done when an intermediate variable(say "BigObject intermediate_var") is returned by another method(say "BigObject B::send(){return intermediate;}" and then the instance of B is likely to go out of scope(deleted). Won't this cause dangling reference? is this why you have suggested using 'const' keyword? if yes, can I later apply 'const_cast' to 'big' argument inside 'my_method' ?  thanks again

Comment: No `BigObject B::send(){return intermediate;}` returns a copy of `intermediate` and there is no problem (if BigObject is well defined).

Comment: @M M. Oh no,sorry, I actually meant  'BigObject & B::send(){return intermediate;}' or 'const BigObject & B::send(){return intermediate;}' (please tell me which one I should use). Otherwise it will do the copy which is not desirable. And again same question, if I use either of the above types as the return type, won't it create a danglig reference?

Comment: It depends of life scope of the variable you referenced. However you can be relax to use of `BigObject send(){return intermediate;}` because of RVO.